# Getting error for setting password field when creating generic user account phpldapadmin

Tags: openldap

I am using openldap 1.2.2 and php 5.5 here is error i am getting. I am new to these things and i m following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-configure-a-basic-ldap-server-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps).

> Error trying to get a non-existent value (appearance, password_hash) `enter code here`

PHP Debug Backtrace

```
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/functions.php (444)
    Function    error (a:5:{i:0;s:67:"Error trying to get a non-existant ...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/ds.php (81)
    Function    debug_dump_backtrace (a:2:{i:0;s:67:"Error trying to get a non-existant ...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (2469)
    Function    getValue (a:2:{i:0;s:10:"appearance";i:1;s:13:"password_hash...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php ()
    Function    drawDefaultHelperPasswordAttribute (a:2:{i:0;O:17:"PasswordAttribute":34:{s:4:"name";s...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/Visitor.php (58)
    Function    call_user_func_array (a:2:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;O:14:"TemplateRender":9:{s:24:"...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/PageRender.php (1006)
    Function    __call (a:2:{i:0;s:4:"draw";i:1;a:3:{i:0;s:13:"DefaultHelp...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/PageRender.php (1006)
    Function    draw (a:3:{i:0;s:13:"DefaultHelper";i:1;O:17:"PasswordAt...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/PageRender.php ()
    Function    drawFormReadWriteValuePasswordAttribute (a:2:{i:0;O:17:"PasswordAttribute":34:{s:4:"name";s...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/Visitor.php (58)
    Function    call_user_func_array (a:2:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;O:14:"TemplateRender":9:{s:24:"...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/PageRender.php (597)
    Function    __call (a:2:{i:0;s:4:"draw";i:1;a:3:{i:0;s:18:"FormReadWri...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/PageRender.php (597)
    Function    draw (a:3:{i:0;s:18:"FormReadWriteValue";i:1;O:17:"Passw...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/PageRender.php ()
    Function    drawFormValueAttribute (a:2:{i:0;O:17:"PasswordAttribute":34:{s:4:"name";s...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/Visitor.php (58)
    Function    call_user_func_array (a:2:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;O:14:"TemplateRender":9:{s:24:"...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (2159)
    Function    __call (a:2:{i:0;s:4:"draw";i:1;a:3:{i:0;s:9:"FormValue";i...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (2159)
    Function    draw (a:3:{i:0;s:9:"FormValue";i:1;O:17:"PasswordAttribu...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php ()
    Function    drawValueAttribute (a:2:{i:0;O:17:"PasswordAttribute":34:{s:4:"name";s...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/Visitor.php (58)
    Function    call_user_func_array (a:2:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;O:14:"TemplateRender":9:{s:24:"...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (1828)
    Function    __call (a:2:{i:0;s:4:"draw";i:1;a:3:{i:0;s:5:"Value";i:1;O...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (1828)
    Function    draw (a:3:{i:0;s:5:"Value";i:1;O:17:"PasswordAttribute":...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php ()
    Function    drawTemplateValuesAttribute (a:1:{i:0;O:17:"PasswordAttribute":34:{s:4:"name";s...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/Visitor.php (58)
    Function    call_user_func_array (a:2:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;O:14:"TemplateRender":9:{s:24:"...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (1817)
    Function    __call (a:2:{i:0;s:4:"draw";i:1;a:2:{i:0;s:14:"TemplateVal...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (1817)
    Function    draw (a:2:{i:0;s:14:"TemplateValues";i:1;O:17:"PasswordA...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php ()
    Function    drawTemplateAttribute (a:1:{i:0;O:17:"PasswordAttribute":34:{s:4:"name";s...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/Visitor.php (58)
    Function    call_user_func_array (a:2:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;O:14:"TemplateRender":9:{s:24:"...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (1602)
    Function    __call (a:2:{i:0;s:4:"draw";i:1;a:2:{i:0;s:8:"Template";i:...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (1602)
    Function    draw (a:2:{i:0;s:8:"Template";i:1;O:17:"PasswordAttribut...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (1527)
    Function    drawShownAttributes (a:0:{})
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (644)
    Function    drawStepForm (a:1:{i:0;i:1;})
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (84)
    Function    visitEnd (a:0:{})
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/htdocs/template_engine.php (55)
    Function    accept (a:0:{})
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/htdocs/cmd.php (59)
    Function    include (a:1:{i:0;s:50:"/usr/share/phpldapadmin/htdocs/temp...)
```

Answer (score 98):

It looks like you've already applied [the diff patches for PHP 5.5](http://sourceforge.net/u/nihilisticz/phpldapadmin/ci/7e53dab990748c546b79f0610c3a7a58431e9ebc/#diff-1).

All you need to do is change `password_hash` in `/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php` on line 2469 to `password_hash_custom`.

Comment: Perfect! Worked for me running openLDAP 1.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 following this exact same guide. @user3117680 please accept this answer.

Comment: Perfect. Worked fine for me too

Comment: strangely perfect : why nobody check it as the correct answer ??